# Gtranslate module "Cannot read property 'G' of undefined" error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, drupal-modules

I'm trying to add additional function to the Gtranslate module in Drupal to make it as a language switch block. When click the gtranslate block, the url will also redirect to the desired language version, like ****/es/****. By that, I can use the gtranslate module for unimportant text, but use entity translation to provide exact human translation for important content.

I'm doing this by write an new js, and attach click event to the gtranslate block item. I use

```
window.location.replace();
```

to redirect the page. The function works fine in Firefox. However, in Chrome, it works randomly. (The redirect always works, but the google translate frame doesn't show sometime.)

The console log catch an error, which is

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'G' of undefined".
```

The google translation frame is also a js file. And the translation frame is rendered by iframe. I have already tried

```
$('iframe').load(function(){...});
```

But this will disable the redirection code. Have no idea where I should go now.

Hope someone meet the same problem before and will provide a solution.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone face the same problem, here my solution to this issue.

It is caused by **asynchronous script load order**. The google translate script is loaded from google CDN, the custom script is loaded from Drupal. Usually, the custom script loads faster than the google translate script. So when you trigger a google translate event in your custom script, it can not find the variables define in google translate script.

A ideal solution will be use `promise` or `callback` function to make the async load in correct order. When I fixed it, I didn't have that much knowledge. So I just use `setTimeOut(function () {}, 500)` to run my custom script asynchronously after google translate script loaded.

It is not a perfect or even good solution, but it did what I want. If I would face to a similar issue, I will post my better solution in future.